# How to calculate this integral

Tags: analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have a function $u(x,y)$ defined on the domain $|x|<\infty, y>0$. I know that
$$ \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(w)}{y^2 + (x-w)^2}dw$$
How can I calculate $u(x,y)$? I have no idea how to tackle this integral.

Comment: What do you know about the function $f(w)$? (You haven't said anything about it.)

Comment: If it helps, in the given integral, substitute $w-x=yz$, with $dw=y\,dz$, and you have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y} &= \frac{y}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x+yz)}{y^2 + y^2z^2}y\,dz\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x+yz)}{1 + z^2}\,dz
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is such that you can reverse the order of integration

$$u(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw \, f(w) \, \int_0^{Y} dy \frac{y}{y^2+(x-w)^2} + g(x)$$

where $g$ is a function of $x$ only.  I used those integration limits over $y$ because you specified $y>0$, but the integral diverges at $\infty$.  Note that the inner integral is

$$\frac12 \log{[Y^2 + (x-w)^2]} - \log{(x-w)}$$

Comment: If $f$ is such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(w) dw = 0$, can the order of integration be reversed? Or must $f$ apply to other requirements?

Comment: I think that depends if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw \, |f(w)| < \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this if it useful...

I'll rename your $w$ as $r$ so it wont confuse things where I use $\omega$ later; your equation is then:

$${\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}u \left( x,y \right) =y\int _{-\infty }
^{\infty }\!{\frac {f \left( r \right) }{{y}^{2}+ \left( x-r \right) ^
{2}}}{dr}$$

The right hand side has the form of a convolution. Thus by the convolution theorem, if we take the Fourier transform we get the product of two functions; one is the Fourier transfrom of $f$ and the other is the Fourier transform of a Lorentzian function which is a damping exponential. In this case it is most useful to use this form of the Fourier transform:
$$U \left( \omega,y \right) =\,\dfrac{1 }{2\pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!u
 \left( x,y \right) {{\rm e}^{-i\omega\,x}}{dx}
$$

$$u \left( x,y \right) =\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!U \left( \omega,y
 \right) {{\rm e}^{i\omega\,x}}{d\omega}
$$

We then get:

$${\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}U \left( \omega,y \right) =F
 \left( \omega \right)G
 \left( \omega ,y\right) $$

$$F \left( \omega \right) =\dfrac{1 }{2\pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!f \left( x
 \right) {{\rm e}^{-i\omega\,x}}{dx}$$

$$G \left( \omega,y \right) =\dfrac{1 }{2\pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!{\frac { \left| y
 \right| {}}{   \left| y \right|  ^
{2}+{x}^{2}}}{\rm e}^{-i\omega\,x}{dx}=1/2\,{{\rm e}^{- \left| \omega \right|  \left| y \right| }}$$

so the differential equation becomes:
$${\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}U \left( \omega,y \right) =1/2\,F
 \left( \omega \right) {{\rm e}^{- \left| \omega \right|  \left| y
 \right| }}$$

which is solvable:
$$U \left( \omega,y \right) =-1/2\,{\frac {F \left( \omega \right) {
{\rm e}^{- \left| \omega \right|  \left| y \right| }}}{ \left| \omega
 \right|  \left| y \right| }}+K(\omega)$$
for $K(\omega)$ a constant as far as $y$ is concerned, and thus:

$$u \left( x,y \right) =\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \left( -1/2\,{
\frac {F \left( \omega \right) {{\rm e}^{- \left| \omega \right| 
 \left| y \right| }}}{ \left| \omega \right|  \left| y \right| }}+K(\omega)
 \right) {{\rm e}^{i\omega\,x}}{d\omega}$$

$$u \left( x,y \right) =\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \left( -1/2\,{
\frac {F \left( \omega \right) {{\rm e}^{- \left| \omega \right| 
 \left| y \right| }}}{ \left| \omega \right|  \left| y \right| }}
 \right) {{\rm e}^{i\omega\,x}}{d\omega}+k(x)$$

Comment: In the last integral, you can integrate over $\omega$ explicitly if you substitute the definition of $F(\omega)$ as a Fourier transform of $f$. Also, since $K(\omega)$ is arbitrary, you might as well say that it is the Fourier transform of an arbitrary function (saying appropriate things about existence), and replace the integral of $K(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega$ with that arbitrary function.

Comment: Sure I take your point about $K$, thinking about it I could also make it a function of $x$ I suppose, but not sure how I would do the explicit integration you speak of with the exponential and $1/|\omega|$ term in there, do you mean with a contour integral and residue approach like in your answer?

Comment: The integral $\int e^{-|\omega||y|+i\omega(x-x')}/|\omega||y|\,d\omega$ has a closed form. Differentiate once w.r.t. $|y|$ to see that it does.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said anything about the function $f(w)$ (you really should).

If $f$ is holomorphic in the complex upper half-plane, and is bounded at infinity, $f(w)=O(1)$, $|w|\to\infty$, $\Im w\geq0$, then you can use Cauchy theorem to write
$$ \frac{y}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(w)}{(w-x)^2+y^2}\,dw
= 2iy\,\text{Res}_{w=x+iy}\frac{f(w)}{(w-x)^2+y^2}
= f(x+iy),$$
so that your function $u(x,y)$ can be written as
$$ u(x,y) = g(x) + \int^y f(x+iy')\,dy', $$
where $g(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$.

Other things will also happen depending on the properties of $f(w)$.